# Error with csv file while importing it into sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, csv

So I am trying to import a csv file into a table with sqlite3 and I get an error, this is the table schema and the command I use to import the file and the error it appears in order:

```
CREATE TABLE Artist(
Art_ID int not null primary key,
Art_Name varchar(30),
Followers int,
Art_Genres varchar(200),
NumAlbums int,
YearFirstAlbum int,
Gender char(1),
Group_Solo varchar(5)
);
sqlite> 
sqlite> .import '| tail -n +2 /Users/adrianogiunta/Desktop/artistDF.csv' Artist
<pipe>:1: expected 8 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
<pipe>:2: expected 8 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
<pipe>:3: expected 8 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
<pipe>:4: expected 8 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
<pipe>:5: expected 8 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
<pipe>:6: expected 8 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
```

and this for the rest of the 1035 rows.

These are the first lines of the csv file:

```
X,Artist,Followers,Genres,NumAlbums,YearFirstAlbum,Gender,Group.Solo
0,Ed Sheeran,52698756,"pop,uk pop",8,2011,M,Solo
1,Justin Bieber,30711450,"canadian pop,dance pop,pop,post-teen pop",10,2009,M,Solo
2,Jonas Brothers,3069527,"boy band,dance pop,pop,post-teen pop",10,2006,M,Group
3,Drake,41420478,"canadian hip hop,canadian pop,hip hop,pop rap,rap,toronto rap",11,2010,M,Solo
4,Chris Brown,9676862,"dance pop,pop,pop rap,r&b,rap",6,2005,M,Solo
5,Taylor Swift,23709128,"dance pop,pop,post-teen pop",10,2006,F,Solo
```

This is what my table shows afterward:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Artist LIMIT 5;
0,Ed Sheeran,52698756,"pop,uk pop",8,2011,M,Solo|||||||
1,Justin Bieber,30711450,"canadian pop,dance pop,pop,post-teen pop",10,2009,M,Solo|||||||
2,Jonas Brothers,3069527,"boy band,dance pop,pop,post-teen pop",10,2006,M,Group|||||||
3,Drake,41420478,"canadian hip hop,canadian pop,hip hop,pop rap,rap,toronto rap",11,2010,M,Solo|||||||
4,Chris Brown,9676862,"dance pop,pop,pop rap,r&b,rap",6,2005,M,Solo|||||||
sqlite>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @AdrianoGiunta it says `expected 8 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL`, so what is actually put in the table?

Comment: Edited my question to answer your question!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the ".separator" setting. You need to tell SQLite3 that the fields are separated by a comma instead of the default separator, otherwise it will not see the separation and - as you discovered - believe each line it's a single field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.import` command by default looks for SQLite's dump format.  You need to enter `.mode csv` before trying to import a CSV.  As the documentation says.